# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest extract specific from the filtered text

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have written a PowerShell script which will extract the required text from the url which is as follows

```
$ExtractData = Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.somesite.com/downloads"
$ExtractData = $ExtractData.tostring() -split "[`r`n]" | select-string "http://somesite.com/download"
```

Which is giving the result as follows

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'http://somesite.com/download/some.exe']);">
```

I thought of writing it splitting by comma separated one but is there any better way to do to get only this thing

`http://somesite.com/download/some.exe`

My try with regex

```
$regex = ‘(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?’
$ExtractData= $ExtractData | select-string -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } 
$ExtractData
```

Which is giving this path but not with `exe`

`http://somesite.com/download`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx) to extract all links in an array of [Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx) records, then collect `Groups[1].Value`:

```ps
$webpage = Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.somesite.com/downloads"
$links = ([regex]'((?:ftp|https?)://\S+?)[''"]').Matches($webpage) |
         ForEach { [Web.HTTPUtility]::HtmlDecode($_.Groups[1].Value) }
```

Note, since we're processing raw HTML the URLs may be HTML-encoded with `&amp;` instead of `&`  so [HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx) was used.